# How to have condition checking (if command) when use referred parameter of the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, if-statement

In my batch file I have the script:

```
set myVar=/someLabel:"%1"
```

I want to write the `if` command for the above script that have the same meaning as below.

```
if <%1 not null> {
  myVar=/someLabel:"%1"
} 
else
{
  myVar=""
}
```

How can I do this?

### [Edit]

The answer from user `hfs` works for me.

The full details of the [`if`](http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm) and [`set`](http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm) command is listed by user `Dave Anderson`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set myVar=
if not "%1" == "" set myVar=/someLabel:%1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure you have delayed variable expansion enabled or the %1 will always be substituted with what is passed to the batch file regardless of your IF statement.

Here are excellent explanations of the [DOS IF](http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm) and [DOS SET](http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm) commands.